# magento 2.0.7 compile error less

Tags: magento2, less-css

my client bought a template from TemplateMonster and I followed their indiciazioni on installation and configuration of the php.ini, I have always an error when I use

```
php bin / magento setup: static-content: deploy

Compilation from source:
frontend / Magento / blank / en_US / TemplateMonster_Megamenu / fonts / font-awesome-4.5.0 / less / list.less
variable @ fa-css-prefix is ​​undefined in /home/omadadesign.com/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/TemplateMonster_Megamenu/fonts/font-awesome-4.5.0/less/list.less file list.less on line 4, column 2
2 | // -------------------------
3 |
4 | . @ {Fa-css-prefix} {-ul
5 | padding-left: 0;
6 | margin-left: @ make-them-width;
> | list-style-type: none;
```

The TemplateMonster Service says it is a server configuration issue but I have tried to install a new version of Magento without their theme and everything works properly.
According to you it depends on the theme? There are server configurations that need to be modified to avoid that mistake?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone needs this. The guys from Template Monster support told me to erase the "less" folder in these two places:

> theme001\app\code\TemplateMonster\Megamenu\view\frontend\web\fonts\font-awesome-4.5.0\
>
> theme001\app\code\TemplateMonster\NewsletterPopup\view\frontend\web\fonts\font-awesome-4.5.0\

After doing that, the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the some different version of font-awesome.

if issue still persist use CDN.
first delete view_processed then try deploying again.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I try now to update the font-awesome file
For now I do not use CDN because the site is on a development server

Comment: I downloaded the 4.7.0 version and updated .less I found but I always this error.
I tried to download the original folder of magento but I always make the same mistake.
But if I use    php bin / magento setup: static-content: deploy
on standard magento I do not mistake and it all works on a regular basis.
You have suggestions for this error?